# How does this program print number's digits in reverse?

Tags: c++, int

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
int nr;
std::cin>>nr;
    while (nr > 0) {
    int digit = nr % 10;
    nr /= 10;
    std::cout<<digit;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain the workflow of this program, basically with the input "32" it outputs "23", that is good, thats my goal, my question is, why does it say "23" instead of just "2", why is the "3" being added in the end if i only said "cout digit". I get that the "3" comes from " nr /= 10", but why is it being outputed near the "2" to farm the answer "23"?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you wrote this piece of code, how can you miss that `while` loop and everything it implies?

Comment: `32%10 == 2; int (32/10) == int(3.2) == 3; 3%10 == 3`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, rolled back your edit. The bad formatting here is a big part of the problem.

Comment: Perhaps formatting the code properly would make it easier to understand.

Comment: @n.m. I am not sure if bad formatting is what OP sees or what OP puts into the question, because he does not know how to format code inside SO editor.

Answer (score 1):

> I get that the "3" comes from `nr /= 10`

Before the program gets to printing 3, it prints 2, which is a *remainder* you get after dividing 32 by 10.

The result of this division is, indeed, 3. Next loop iteration picks it up, and prints it, because `3 % 10` is 3.

Answer (score 1):

The while makes two iterations. It tests if the condition is true, executes what is inside. Digit takes the value 2, nr becomes 3, it outputs 2. Then for the second iteration, nr is still bigger than 0, so digit becomes 3, nr becomes 0, it outputs 3. The condition is no longer met, so it exits the loop. (Using 23 as an input, that is)

Answer (score 0):

## Flow of your code

Your code works a follows (assuming you have entered the number 32, thus the variable *nr* is 32).

### First iteration

#### Step 1

> ```
> while(32 > 0)
> ```
>
> **result:** true.

#### Step 2

> ```
> int digit = nr % 10;
> ```
>
> **result:** *digit* now contains the value *2* due to the *remainder (%)* operation.

#### Step 3

> ```
> nr /= 10;
> ```
>
> **result:** *nr* now contains the value *3*, because *32 / 10* results in *3.2* which is a float, but since you are assigning this
>   number to an integer it ***implicit converts*** to the number *3*.

#### Step 4

> ```
> std::cout<<digit;
> ```
>
> **result:** 2 (the variable *digit* is still unaffected since the *remainder operation* 2).

### Second iteration

#### Step 1

> ```
> while(3 > 0)
> ```
>
> **result:** true (the condition in the while-loop get called again and the variable *nr* is *3*).

#### Step 2

> ```
> int digit = nr % 10;
> ```
>
> **result:** *digit* now contains the value *3*, because *3 % 10 = 3*.

#### Step 3

> ```
> nr /= 10;
> ```
>
> Is not relevant anymore for any changes of the flow besides that the while-loop will terminate.

#### Step 4

> ```
> std::cout<<digit;
> ```
>
> **result:** 3 (since the *digit* variable is now *3*).
>   So the complete output will be ***23***.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, but I have one more question, second iteration, step 3, shouldnt "nr" be "0"? because 3 / 10 = 0.3 ? Or I am confusing this with the integer (int)? Sorry, Im new to coding, and english is not my first language

Comment: @DariusValeriu That is correct since 0.3 is a float it will be converted to 0 since nr is a integer. What basically happens when you assign a float to an integer is that the number after the decimal point will drop. So for example 0.9 becomes 0 and 2.3 becomes 2.

Answer (score 0):

Because the while loop means the code within it is repeated until the condition is no longer satisfied. For a two digit number the print statement will therefore be executed twice.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers, I cant believe I forgot about the condition nr > 0